# Configuring jtaTransactionManager to LocalSessionFactoryBean with Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta

How to configure LoanSessionFactoryBean to use a JTA transaction manager with Hibernate 4?

With Hibernate 3.x following configuration works, but in Hibernate 4 the [LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) no longer has `jtaTransactionManager` property

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
    p:configLocation="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"
    p:jtaTransactionManager-ref="jtaTransactionManager" />
```

I am using Spring 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Spring 3.1.1 doesn't have the attibute jtaTransactionManager. Maybe they forgot to add it.

They added it in Spring 3.1.4. So I think you should move up to that version.